# MYSQL Delete FROM All Tables Where Condition TRUE

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, delete-row

I have at least 30 MySQL Tables with full of data. I have a MySQL event, which should delete all rows from all tables where the `*.uid = (SELECT uid FROM 'cdelete' WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  date ) >=1)` -> The result should be `1`, because only the customers with the id `1` is in the `delete` table. So I want to remove every rows where the `uid = 1`

What I've tried so far:

```
DELETE cdelete, customers, orders 
FROM cdelete 
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = cdelete.uid
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.uid = cdelete.uid
WHERE cdelete.uid = (SELECT uid FROM 'cdelete' WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  date ) >=1)
```

It seems that this kind of deletion is impossible, or I made some mistake.. Any idea how to delete from all tables where the uid is retrived from the `SELECT uid FROM 'cdelete' WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  date ) >=1)` statement?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the subquery, just test the date directly in the `WHERE` condition.

```
DELETE cdelete, customers, orders 
FROM cdelete 
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.id = cdelete.uid
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.uid = cdelete.uid
WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  cdelete.date ) >=1
```

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` in case there are no related rows in the other tables.

Also, if you configure `customers` and `orders` with a foreign key and `ON DELETE CASCADE` then you only need to delete from `cdelete` -- the related rows in the other tables will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please show me a way how to use the `ON DELETE CASCADE`? I've found nothing about it on the internet...

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: @Barmar Let's say, I have the same tables like in the picture above, except the `orders` table doesn't have the `id 3` row, only the first two. So if I want to use the statement you have provided above, it won't work somewhy. Maybe because  the `orders` table doesn't contains the `id`? If so how can I still delete from the other table even if the `orders` table doesn't contain the `id 3` row?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`